# Open new window if there are no problems with from validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that validates some basic form info. After user entered info and if there are no problems with validation there should open a new window onclick. if there are problems with form fields the user should be prompted to fix what is wrong and the window should not open. Now I have attempted to write a code for this but the problem I have is that my window opens regardless whether there is a problem with the form or not. The window should only open if there are no problems with form.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction as to what I can do to solve this little problem.

code follows:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var nat = document.getElementById("nat").value;
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var town = document.getElementById("town").value;
var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;


if (name == "" )
{
window.alert("Please Enter your Full Name");    
}


checkNr= isNaN(phone)
if(checkNr == true)
{
window.alert("PHONE NUMBER: You can only enter numbers. Please try again");
}

else if (phone == "")
{
window.alert("please enter your phone number")  ;
}

if (nat == "")
{
window.alert("Please enter your nationality")
}


if(town =="")
{
window.alert("Please enter your town")
}

if(zip=="")
{
window.alert("Please enter your zip code")
}


if (userName=="")
{
window.alert("Please enter your username")
}

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="subscribe" action="mailto:" >
FULLNAME: </strong><input type="text"  id="name"/><br />
  PHONE NR: <input type="text" id="phone" /><br />
  NATIONALITY:<input type="text" id="nat" /><br />
  Address:<input type="text" id="address" /><br />
  Town:<input type="text" id="town" /><br />
  Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zip" /><br />
 Username: <input type="text" id="userName" /><br />
 Date Of lesson:<input type="text" id="dOl" value="dd/mm/yy" />


 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="validate(), openWindow()" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to contain any conditional logic that decides when the window should and should not be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, `validate` and `openWindow` are written sequentially, and will execute regardless of either's outcome.

What you can do is something like this.

```
function validate() {
    //If the validation fails, return false, else return true.
}
```

Change your `onClick` attribute to

```
onclick="if(validate()) openWindow();"
```

Now, if the validation goes through successfully, a new window will be opened. If not, no bueno.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML you have
`<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="validate(), openWindow()" />`
says that call `validate` function and call `openWindow` function one after the other. So regardless of the validation state, window will open.

What I would suggest is to call function `openWindow` in function `validate` at the end of it based on the state of the validation.

HTML would be `<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="validate()" />`

Script would be

```
function validate () {
  // do the necessary stuff here
  if (!hasErrors) {
    openWindow();
  }
}
```